# Moving from one activity to another by click on card created in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, cardview

**#beginner** ...i created the  cards list [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hODwN.png) using list view
i want to get to the new screen frm the click on the card made in list view...please help me to solve  this problem .... please give me the full details of the ways by which i can do the task to solve my problems....
 .... here is what i coded::::

***Main_Activity.java***

```
package com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.Adapter.subjectAdapter;
import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.R;
import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.model.ListDetails;
import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.model.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<model>models;
    private subjectAdapter subjectAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        models = ListDetails.getList();

        subjectAdapter = new subjectAdapter(MainActivity.this,models);
        listView.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

***model.java***

```
package com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.model;

/**
 * Created by ecspc on 25/10/2017.
 */

public class model {

    private int subjectImage;
    private String subjectTitle;
    private String count;

    public model(int subjectImage, String subjectTitle, String count) {
        this.subjectImage = subjectImage;
        this.subjectTitle = subjectTitle;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getSubjectImage() {
        return subjectImage;
    }

    public void setSubjectImage(int subjectImage) {
        this.subjectImage = subjectImage;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getSubjectTitle() {
        return subjectTitle;

    }

    public void setSubjectTitle(String subjectTitle) {
        this.subjectTitle = subjectTitle;
    }
}
```

***subjectAdapter.java***

```
package com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ColorSpace;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.R;
import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.model.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ecspc on 25/10/2017.
 */

public class subjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<model> models;

    public subjectAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<model> models) {
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return models.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_view,null);

            ImageView images = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);
            TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardTitle);
            TextView count = convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
            model model = models.get(position);
            images.setImageResource(model.getSubjectImage());
            title.setText(model.getSubjectTitle());
            count.setText(model.getCount());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**ListDetails.java**

```
package com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.model;

import com.android.mezohn.nepstudy.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ecspc on 25/10/2017.
 */

public class ListDetails {

    public static ArrayList<model> getList(){
        ArrayList<model> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        subjectList.add(new model(R.drawable.phy,"Physics","4 chapters available"));
        subjectList.add(new model(R.drawable.che,"Chemistry","5 chapters available "));
        subjectList.add(new model(R.drawable.que,"Model Questions","10 model Questions available"));

       return subjectList;
    }
}
```

i am a beginner so i hope i would get sufficient help from it.

Comment: remove the #beginner comment (and all mentions of beginner), it doesn't add anything to the question; also, tell us what you expected to happen, and what actually happens

Answer (score 0):

So it appears you have not attempted to add a listener to your ListView. You can do this via [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        //.. launch your new activity here using Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Another note, you should really get better at naming your classes. Recommended reading: [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

You should also read: [Making a listview scroll smooth](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) which talks about the ViewHolder pattern, or simply move to a RecyclerView once you know a bit more android.

Comment: sir ..thanks for your reply                                                                                                        i have two confusions regarding this ,,,,,                                                                           1) do i have to place that code in mainactivity.java file or list details .java file????                                                          2) i do have an adapter in the previous code , do i have to create a new one...

Comment: add this code to MainActivity where you have a ListView reference, and no you do not need to create a new adapter